# Why is there a village called "Cat Cat Bamboo" (猫猫箐)?

Tags: meaning

I was scrolling through the map when I stumbled across a village called:

> [image]
>
> 猫猫箐

[Baidu Baike](https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E7%8C%AB%E7%8C%AB%E7%AE%90%E6%9D%91/9366167?fr=aladdin) has an entry on the place but it doesn't talk about where they got their name from. It seems quite bizarre. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found an answer while I was writing up the question & figured I might as well share it.

---

[Sohu](http://www.sohu.com/a/194108024_708300) has an article entitled:

> **你以为昆明的路名都是瞎起的？**

in which they have an explanation of the name:

> **猫猫箐**：在西山龙门西南面的山里，因为曾有虎豹（俗称猫猫）出没得名。此外，在嵩明县阿子营乡东南部也有一个猫猫箐，因“从前箐里有野猫出没而得名。”
>
> [image: pic]

They claim that the area used to have tigers and leopards that would emerge from the bamboo groves on the mountains.

I'm not sure about the assertion that they used to have leopards, though. In South Western Mandarin 猫猫 can definitely be a jocular term for tigers.

[《成都方言》](https://www.tiaodengyedu.com/html/348/348599/111232685.html) has the following example:

> 猫猫 maomao ①猫。成都童谣：“～你不走，乖乖瞌睡有；～你不来，乖乖瞌睡来；～你不咬，乖乖要睡了。”②趣称老虎：～跑到村子里来了。亦作“花猫猫”。

Comment: 猫猫 meaning "tiger" really gives a false sense of security to non-locals...

Comment: @droooze I'm sure it's a taboo-thing, again.

Comment: yes, well; a taboo word that non-locals can't misunderstand would be more optimal. 貓貓 sounds like what a child would call a cute furry cat, and if I didn't have any information I would assume that the local bamboo forest was just filled with cute furry things.

Comment: @droooze You might be also tempted to believe that you could also grab a cup of joe there, while hanging out with all those cute furry kittens.